# How to select the xpath where the drop down is displayed

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have many rows in a grid, listing just two below.  When I select a row and click on a drop down, then only it displays the drop down menu.  I want to select the **Account Open** drop down item only where it is displayed.  What is the **Xpath** that I can use to achieve this?  I noticed that where it is displayed, the style says

```
style="top: 446px; display: block; left: 76px; right: auto;">;
```

where as the others says **display:  none**.

I came up with the below, but want to have only one Xpath with all in.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]//name['colActionDropdownMenu']")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, 'AccountOpen')]')
```

HTML :

```
<ul name="colActionDropdownMenu" class="dropdown-menu action-dropdown-menu noselect" dropdown-menu="" role="menu" style="top: 446px; display: none; left: 76px; right: auto;">
         <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="action in grid.appScope.validActions">
                <a href="" id="AccountOpen" ng-click="grid.appScope.doAction(action)">Account Open</a>
            </li><li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="action in grid.appScope.validActions">
        </ul>
<ul name="colActionDropdownMenu" class="dropdown-menu action-dropdown-menu noselect" dropdown-menu="" role="menu" style="top: 269px; display: block; left: 76px; right: auto;">
<li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="action in grid.appScope.validActions">
                <a href="" id="AccountOpen" ng-click="grid.appScope.doAction(action)">Account Open</a>
            </li><li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="action in grid.appScope.validActions">
        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you see the html code in the question?

Comment: Why can't you use `driver.find_element_by_id("AccountOpen")`?

Comment: that would not work, since that id is there for many rows that is hidden.  i have to use something like, but not sure the complete xpath to use. 

//ul[@style = 'top: 319px; display: block; left: 76px; right: auto;']/li/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath

```
"//ul[@name='colActionDropdownMenu'][contains(@style,'display: block')]//a[@id='AccountOpen']"
```

You can remove the id part for the link if you want.